# NodeJS QuerySelector - Select and click the Pay Button for a Stripe Form

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, autofill, queryselector

I am trying to implement the program to click the play button on the stripe forms

https://stripe.dev/elements-examples/

I have tried these 4 different approaches to selecting the pay button, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

you can use this function to fill in the components

```
function fillByName(name, value) {
    let element = document.getElementsByName(name)[0];
    if (element) {
        autofill(element, value);
    }   
}
```

with implementation like

```
// FILL INFO
fillByName('cardnumber', 1111111111111111);
fillByName('exp-date', '06/29);
fillByName('cvc', '111');


// PAY
document.querySelector('#elements_examples.form.pay_button').click();
document.querySelector('elements_examples.form.pay_button').click();
document.querySelector('.elements_examples.form.pay_button').click();
document.querySelector('.button, .submit').click();
```

Comment: You're trying to select by a `data` field. A better way would be to assign the button an `id` and then use `document.querySelector('#whatever_id_you_chose')`

Comment: how can I assign the button an ID? in the html DOM I can only see <button type="submit" data-tid="elements_examples.form.pay_button">Pay $25</button>

Comment: what about on this site? https://stripe-payments-demo.appspot.com/

Comment: There's a good guide for Chrome DevTools at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/dom (similar guides exist for other browsers)